# multiplying by -1 for sorted() doesn't work for string data in python

Tags: python, sorting

My list condition are in String. so, I want to sorted the second condition from big to small, but "-" does not working for me. my code is:

```
import operator
a = int(input())
my_list = []
for i in range(a):
    data = list(map(str, input().split()))
    my_list.append(data)

result = sorted(my_list, key= operator.itemgetter(2, 1, 0))

for i in range(len(result)):
    print(result[i][0])
```

for input for example:

```
6
Elon 22 2017
Jakob 22 2017
ali 20 2018
sina 30 2008
donald 33 2005
jo 31 2018
```

the first item is name. second is age. and the last is year. so, the Priority for me is year, age from big to small and the name. I know, that i can use sorted() and choose the priority, but the second condition must be in reverse. I was searching, and found that if I use "-" before the condition and then call "reverse=True" the condition that have "-", will be reversed. but my condition is string and it does not working!

now, the output is:

```
donald
sina
Elon
Jakob
ali
jo
```

**but I expected:**

```
donald
sina
Elon
Jakob
jo
ali
```

Comment: Could you please post your expected output?

Comment: @Bogota Sure. I add the output on the end of my post.

Comment: Please include the code where you use "-" and that does not work instead of just describing it, along with the complete error message.

Comment: @timgeb Thank you for you answer. The code in below was answering my question and it is work now.

Comment: @Mehran Good to hear that. In the future, please don't rely on people correctly guessing. :)

Comment: @timgeb Yes, Sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (x[2], -int(x[1])))
for x in result:
    print(x[0])
```

**Output**

```
donald
sina
Elon
Jakob
jo
ali
```